# What is the best way to hit a URL in Android without using a WebView?

Tags: android, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

So what I want to do is hit a URL without opening the browser. The URL is basically the way I am interfacing with some hardware I am playing around with (ie by hitting this URL it will trigger something in the hardware).

For example, I just want a button in my Android application to hit "localhost:8080/test" without opening the Android browser. The only thing I would like to know is whether my HTTP request succeeded or failed.

Thanks

Comment: see here: [Make an HTTP request with android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Comment: delayed, but thanks for the help! works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I would check for the response code from the http request to check for success or failure.